# Is there any technical reason why the denoiser isn't a compositing node?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, denoise

I enjoy having the option to denoise renders in Blender 2.79. However, it seems like it would be much more intuitive if there was a denoising node in the compositor for a number of reasons. For example:

1. One could control the degree to which an image is denoised (completely denoised images seem more fake than renders with a little bit of noise)
2. One could tweak the denoising settings without having to completely re-render
3. People could have more control over which parts of the image get denoised
4. People could denoise images and things without having to put them in the 3D viewport first.

Are there any technical reasons why it isn't a compositing node? If not, where is a place where I can make a feature request?

Comment: The denoiser specifically requires 3D data collected from the Blender scene to work, and can't denoise non rendered external images.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Can't the compositor collect all the 3D data that the Denoiser does?

Comment: The compositor is not aware of a 3D scene, if there is any at all, since it doesn't require one to work, other than the render passes that are handed to it, as far as I know

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Okay, but suppose the denoising settings were at least changeable after the render. It seems really silly to have to rerender something just because you got some weird denoising artifact that could have been prevented with different settings.